# How to know all pids of forks in forks?

Tags: bash, process, fork, execve

example:

```
$ cat main.sh
#!/bin/bash
./child_level1.sh &

$ cat child_level1.sh
#!/bin/bash
./child_level2.sh &

$ cat child_level2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo Hi, fork()s! &

$ ./main.sh # outputs Hi, fork()s
```

target: write a script **follow.sh** which runs $1 and collects pids of all forks. Like that:

```
$ ./follow.sh ./main.sh
[pid_main.sh] [pid_child_level1.sh] [pid_child_level2.sh] [pid_of_echo]
```

4 numbers for that example). The numbers may appear since some time. Maybe there is a known name for utility **follow.sh** like **pidtracer**?

Comment: Is this homework?  The output from `ps` contains information about the parent process ID, or if you are satisfied with a Linux-only solution, you can access this in machine-readable form from the `/proc` filesystem.

Comment: Not at all. It's not a homework.

Comment: Example where such solution (with =~ pstree) doesn't works:
($ main.sh &)
(it's create => main.sh-+-child_level1.sh-+-child_level2.sh)
(then we killall -r level1)
(main.sh and child_level2.sh doesn't connected with PPID)

Comment: You can `strace -f main.sh` and look for the `fork`s in the output, or perhaps create a simple `LD_PRELOAD` wrapper to print each PID after `fork()`ing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tripleee. I think it is a good solution.

```
$ cat ./wrap_fork.c
//fork wrapper.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t fork(void){
  FILE * f = fopen("/tmp/dearforks","a");
  typedef pid_t (*t_fork)(void);
  t_fork org_fork = dlsym(((void *) -1l), "fork");
  pid_t p = org_fork();
  fprintf(f,"pid = %i\n",p);
  fclose(f);
  return p;
}

$ gcc -fPIC -c -Wall wrap_fork.c
$ gcc -shared wrap_fork.o -ldl -lstdc++ -o wrap_fork.so
```

now **follow.sh**

```
$ cat follow.sh
#!/bin/bash
export LD_PRELOAD=./wrap_fork.so
$* &
```

now, it's time for execution:

```
./follow.sh ./main.sh
```

and the result:

```
$ cat /tmp/dearforks
pid = 2065
pid = 0
pid = 2066
pid = 0
pid = 2067
pid = 0
```

It's have a taste of what I want. Except some zeros) (*And pids after calling **sleep** in future:(* )

Why there are *zeros* in the result?

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$!` gives the PID of the most recent command you ran in the background.  So try `echo $!` immediately following each background command.

Comment: in follow.sh $! returns only pid of main.sh& and we need pids of child1, child2 and echo

Comment: @JoJa So you want all of main.sh's siblings?

Comment: @JoJa: right, so you need to return the PIDs at each level.  Echo, print to file, something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using a temporary file whose name is stored in an environment variable:

```
$ cat main.sh
#!/bin/bash
export mytrace="pids-from-$$.tmp"
echo $$ >| "$mytrace"
./child_level1.sh &

$ cat child_level1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ >> "$mytrace"
./child_level2.sh &

$ cat child_level2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ >> "$mytrace"
echo -n "The pids are: "
tr \\n ' ' < "$mytrace"
echo
rm -f "$mytrace"
```

Comment: I my history I can't change anything except follow.sh. In real some of them very long bash files and other .bin files)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find all the pids, because the scripts exit too fast. If they run long enough, you can use

```
ps axo ppid,pid,comm
```

to get the parent pid, script pid and command name of all processes. You can then build a tree starting from your first script pid `$!`.

Comment: if somebody killed (or crashed) child_level1 then the ppid of child_level2 will be set to 1. I think we need smth like strace -f

Comment: @JoJa Correct, that's why I said "If they run long enough"!